# Windows Mobile GPS

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a requirement such that I will need to fetch the current location (i.e. longitude & latitude) in a windows mobile desktop application. It would be great to have any kind of detailed document for the beginners in windows mobile gps application.

Also Do I really need to have an extra gps device connected to my phone?

Comment: What version of WM are you using?

Comment: "windows mobile desktop application" is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your WM phone is somewhat new ... manufactured in the past year or so ... there's a good chance you have native on-board GPS support.  Check your settings.  If not, and depending on the version of WM you're running, you'll be able to support Bluetooth GPS connections (though it makes it more difficult to do the development if this is your first effort).

There are several samples, tutorials, and of course there is the actual .NET Compact Framework sample also.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably use Microsoft GPS Intermediate Driver (GPSID)
[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202086.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202086.aspx)

When you install Windows Mobile SDK you will see a full sample in installed folder.
C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CS\GPS

In my case I used Intermec and that has a special documentation. Maybe your device has too. Please check your products web site too.
http://www.intermec.com/public-files/articles/en/DevelopingSoftware4_CN3IntegratedGPS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get your hands on a Windows Mobile device with built-in GPS. Then you start looking at the `GPSOpenDevice` family of GPS functions in the Windows Mobile SDK docs.

Answer (score 0):

If your GPS receiver is separate from the device you are using, you're likely going to interface with it either through Bluetooth or through a serial cable.

Once you connect to it through SerialPort class you'll likely be reading in NMEA data. You can find NMEA strings and what they mean here: http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)