# Show Route Maps on Windows mobile 6 using GPS

Tags: dictionary, windows-mobile, gps, windows-mobile-gps

I am Working on Window mobile 6 Application Which has Some GPS Functionality.
I know how to get the Current Position and How to get the Distance between two Points.

But i want is to display a Map on the Screen with a Highlighted route between two Points and the navigation between them if possible, Using the AGPS only. The client does not want me use Maps(ie google or yahho or bing).

I have already gone through these links

[GPS in windows mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493253/gps-in-windows-mobile)

[Windows Mobile GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954418/windows-mobile-gps)

[Use GPS with Windows Mobile Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586942/use-gps-with-windows-mobile-phone)

and some other but not able to find out.

If any body has done it or know some good source, Shareit wit me.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand this question correctly?  You want to draw a route between two points on a map, but without using any third-party mapping libraries or controls?

If so, the solution is easily stated, but really complex to implement.  All you have to do is generate a map file that "knows" about all roads and their spatial relationship to one another, GPS locations  and, possibly, other geographic points.  That would allow you to draw the map and locte a point on the map given a GPS location.

You then need to run something like the classic "travelling salesman" problem to determine the shortest route between the two points of interest.

Finally you simply "highlight" that route in your drawing code.

See, simple to explain.  There are entire companies (like Mapquest, Decarta, etc), or divisions of companies (like Google and Microsoft) that have dedicated years to solving this problem.  Unless you plan on becoming a mapping solution provider, I question whether rolling your own makes much business sense.